# Possible Accessibility Event delivery bug in ICS. Event is delivered twice. All works fine in HoneyComb or lower

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a question about a possible Accessibility issue/bug I found in ICS.

I'm working for K-NFB, Kurzweil - National Federation of the Blind our e-book reader allows for continuous TTS reading through Android's accessibility services. We needed to roll our own Accessibility Service to be able to get notified when a TTS utterance stops speaking (e.g. auto-turn pages and such).

Our accessibility service is package specific and is not registered as a 'default' accessibility service. On Android 3.x and lower, it works fine, because if a package specific service can handle an accessibility event, the default service won't receive it. However on ICS, both our service and the default service (Talkback) receives the Accessibility Event. This causes utterance to be spoken twice. Once by our service and once by Talkback.

Is the accessibility team for Android aware of this issue?

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23933

If this is not an bug, what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the code snippet where you set the config variables (packageNames, etc) ? For ICS, have you tried configuring via an XML file?  Details are here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

Comment: I am having the same problem too, I did put android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
in my accessibility service xml configuration file, but I still hear the utterance spoken twice, one by Talkback and one by my own accessibility service. If I turn off TalkBack I'll just hear the utterance spoken once, just by my own service. I am using a Nexus 4, with JellyBean 4.2 Have anyone got it working? Any other tricks? Thanks very much!

Comment: This is a bug in Samsung devices.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that your Accessibility Service has not been correctly registered for the AccessibilityEvent ***types*** that you want to handle. As an experiment, add the following attribute to your AccessibiltyServiceInfo XML configuration:

```
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
```

This attribute signals the framework that you want to handle all AccessibilityEvents for the specific packages you have registered for. If that stops the double processing then you have your answer. You can then experiment with requesting only the EventTypes that you are interested in. The XML configuration EventTypes are listed here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AccessibilityService_accessibilityEventTypes

You can also dynamically set the event type filtering using the AccessibilityServiceInfo.eventTypes() method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo.html#eventTypes